# Adding the highest odd and even in a list

Tags: python

I have a list and I'm trying to write a program that finds the highest odd and even number and add them together then print the number.

```
numbers = [2,3,4,5,6,1,0,7]

def solution(numbers):
   lodd = -1
   leven = -1
   for n in numbers:
       n = int(n)
       if n % 2 == 0 and n > leven:
            leven = n
            print(n)

    for n in numbers:
        n = int(n)
        if n % 2 != 0 and n > lodd:
            lodd = n
            print(n)

solution(numbers)
```

Comment: Help with what? What's the problem with what you've done?

Comment: BTW, you can simply do `print(sum(max(n for n in numbers if n % 2 == k) for k in [0, 1]))`.

Comment: (Flagged as "not reproducible" as this is too specific to help future readers)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like :

```
odds = [element for element in numbers if element % 2 != 0]
evens = [element for element in numbers if element % 2 == 0]

print(max(odds) + max(evens))
```

Comment: BINGO -  now for me to research element for element :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why use two loops where you could just iterate once?

Iterate and save the max per condition (odd or even), then `sum` the result.

###### positive numbers only

```
numbers = [2,3,4,5,6,1,0,7]

out = {0: 0, 1: 0}

for n in numbers:
    if n>out[n%2]:
        out[n%2] = n

sum(out.values())
# 13
```

###### more generic code to handle negative numbers as well and missing odd/even values

This handles possible missing evens or odds:

```
numbers = [1,3,1,5,1,-7]

out = {0: None, 1: None}

for n in numbers:
    k = n%2
    if out[k] is None or n>out[k]:
        out[k] = n

sum(v for v in out.values() if v)
# 5
```